# Reference a specific value in a csv and move-item according

Tags: powershell, csv, move

I am working on the sceond part of a move script and I am very close to a solution. I have one small stumbling block in an otherwise complete script.

I am sure this script can be condensed to make it more efficient but:

```
$move = $sourceDir + "\" + $_.fileName      
$csv | % {
            if ($_.folder -eq 'Y')
            {
                $move = $sourceDir + "\" + $_.fileName
                mi $_ "$move"
            }
            mi $_ "$move"
        } #end for
```

The problem I have is that I need the initial move folder declared as the first value of the csv fileName colomn as it will always be a Y for the folder colomn which determines if the file is moved to that folder or the last one which had a carresponding Y.

The if statement will update the $move variable to the new move folder if present otherwise it will just keep the move folder as the last iteration and move it to that folder.

I am unsure how to reference the first value in the csv i have tried to reference it as an array fileName[1] but it did not work.

Im hopeful it is a small fix.

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Craig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the value with the following:

```
$csv[0].fileName
```

In this example, 'fileName' is the column name in the CSV file for which we want to grab the first value ($csv[0]).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much. sometimes simple steps like this are impossible to find, this will be a massive help to me!